# AWS ELB handling less request than single instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat6, load-testing, amazon-elb

I am performing load testing on my web-app behind the AWS ELB. I have tested two scenario
1) Check throughput directly generate load on tomcat instance
2) Check throughput by generate load on AWS ELB.

I am using Apache Benchmark tool for load testing. I have observed that AWS ELB gives less req/sec than directly throughput on instance. I want to know that what is the problem in AWS ELB that causing the low throughput.

Comment: Are you using VPC? or just standard EC2 instances?

Comment: How big is the difference. Hard numbers please.

Comment: @kevin Willock. Yes I am in VPC.

Comment: @MarkThomas. When I am generating load on EC2 it gives 750 req/sec. and when I am going through ELB then it gives 300 req/sec.

Comment: Ouch. I'd expect a little bit less since using any load-balancer inevitably adds a few percent of overhead but not that much. Either you aren't comparing comparable servers or something isn't set up right. Hard to tell what the problem might be from the limited information available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the background (deep inside the Amazon jungle) ELBs are basically just very simple small instances running LB software, so they definately have a performance limit and this is probably what you are hitting. Now, ELBs are designed to scale with increasing load (requests, not connections I believe) but this scaling only happens over a five minute period so if you have a synthetic test that ramps up in less time than that then you will hit problems.

Two solutions:

1. Ramp up very slowly, but that's boring.
2. Raise a support call with Amazon and ask for your ELB instances to be 'pre warmed'. Tell them how much load you want to test to and they will make some adjustments accordingly.

Comment: An article: Best Practices in Evaluating Elastic Load Balancing at http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479 discusses pre-warning and ramp up.  "We [Amazon] recommend that you increase the load at a rate of no more than 50 percent every five minutes."